# looping through a 2D array 3 items at a time (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble trying to figure out a way to move through a 2D array 3 items at a time mostly because it has to be done in a specific way.

The array itself has individuals as rows and loci for columns. I have to take 2 individuals at a time and compare them with every third until the end:

```
So if there are 5 individuals the total individual comparisons would be
0,1,2, 0,1,3, 0,1,4, 1,2,3, 1,2,4 and 2,3,4
```

For each of these comparisons, I have to compare their alleles at each locus (each column represents an allele, so two columns is one locus). So it looks something like this

```
   locus1 locus2 locus3 ...  
   0  1   2  3   4  5 
 0 1  2   3  4   5  6 
 1 7  8   9  10  11 12
 2 13 14  15 16  17 18 
 3 19 20  21 22  23 24
 4 25 26  27 28  29 30 

As a definite example of what I mean, say I have the first set: 0,1,2. 
The first comparison would be of the alleles: 1,2, 7,8 and 13, 14. 
The next comparison would be of the alleles: 3,4, 9,10 and 15,16.
The last (assuming three loci) would be: 5,6, 11,12, and 17,18.
```

For every set of 6 alleles, I have to do a comparison. I already have finished the code for the comparison testing. Im just not sure how to properly loop through this 2D array. What I am thinking about is psuedo-code like this:

```
 for each pair of individuals (i,j)
   for each locus l 
     for each individual k, not i or j
       if comparison test works 
         great
       else 
         better luck next time
```

I do not want a direct answer. I would just like guidance as to how to tackle this keeping array boundaries in mind. I have not done a search like this before.

I appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this that I can think of. These days, we have classic external iterations, and the more modern (but slightly limited) internal stream iterations. I'll show you both.

I'm assuming your collection/array is of type `Allele` and called `alleles`, but that's entirely arbitrary.

For an external iteration, it would be something like this:

```
for(Allele i : alleles) {
    for(Allele j : alleles) {
        if(i == j) continue;
        for(Allele k : alleles) {
            if(i == j || i == k) continue;
            doComparison(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, test for equivalencies before entering the next loop, and if you find one, skip to the next entry.

For internal iteration (functional/streams), it would be something like this

```
alleles.stream().forEach(i -> 
    alleles.stream().filter(j -> i != j).forEach(j -> 
        alleles.stream().filter(k -> k != i && k != j).forEach(k -> 
            doComparison(i, j, k)
        )
    )
);
```

In this instance, it may be a bit more efficient, as the `filter(…)` methods remove each potential conflict before beginning the iteration. If you're dealing with much more than three, though, you may have to get clever with your iterations.

Hopefully that will do it. Good luck!

Comment: The first method should also work if instead of allele type I just have a simple integer value sitting at the position. It seems as though the first method is disregarding loci altogether and instead just comparing the values. Is that true, or am I misjudging?

Comment: I will admit that I'm not entirely clear on the concept of loci.

Comment: Loci just being the genetic makeup of the animal being tested. At each locus there is one allele from the mother and one from the father. Here, I tried to simplify it by placing each allele as an int in its own array index. So, if there are 5 individuals, each with 3 loci, then there are 6 alleles for each individual for a total of 30 alleles.